# Display data on Model window grails

Tags: grails

I am a newbie in Grails. On click of a button, I'm calling jQuery AJAX function. This function calls an action in a controller and renders the `VO` object as JSON. Now, this JSON is of a VO and I need to display this data in GSP which is opened as a model window. I am able to access the action output in jQuery. But how to use the same in GSP? (`VO` has Huge data). Can I keep data in session etc? Please advice

Comment: Please include some code. I believe many people are finding it hard to understand your question. Hope someone can help you.

Comment: If you're trying to render the JSON data on the page after receiving the Ajax response, there's nothing GSP-specific that you need to do. You'd just update the DOM as usual. GSP is server-side while Ajax is client-side. By the time the page is ready for an Ajax request the GSP had long completed. If you're trying to render the same data into the page on the server-side (GSP) that could be done as well. Just state which is it that you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What I able to understand is that you want to open the `VO` data as GSP renders like you are doing on the click of a button? Am I correct?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Yes. I can update DOM but is there any other better way to do it. because there are many elements i have to update

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal Yes. on completion of ajax request, I have to display JSON data on a model window